# Websphere Application Server - Spring MVC - java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/codehaus/jackson/map/type/TypeFactory.type

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, websphere, nosuchmethoderror

I am using WAS 8.0 due to client restrictions to deploy a Spring MVC application.
I have some controllers defining a tiny web service.

I tried to deploy in some common servers and it runs properly, but when i try to deploy into WAS this is the situation:

- I can use GET services, not depending of what elements are getting.
- I can render the GET calls in XML.
- I can render the GET calls in JSON using jackson annotations.

But when I try to use some of the POST calls, the application throws this error (got from WAS JVM System Out):

```
0000002c webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[myApp]: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/codehaus/jackson/map/type/TypeFactory.type(Ljava/lang/reflect/Type;Lorg/codehaus/jackson/type/JavaType;)Lorg/codehaus/jackson/type/JavaType;
at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.getJavaType(MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.java:219)
at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.canRead(MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.java:134)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:130)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.readWithMessageConverters(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:180)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:95)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:77)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:162)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:123)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1225)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:775)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:457)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1032)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3763)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:975)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:195)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:453)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:515)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:306)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:277)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:166)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1691)
```

In the last version of the org.codehaus.jackson.mapper library, the function the error is refering is deprecated. So I tried to switch from version 1.0 to 1.9.12 of the library clean deploying it with every change (to avoid class version collision).

After some Googling i find a post that sais it must be a class loader problem, so I select `PARENT_LAST` config in WAS. But nothing happened.

I dont realy now what is happening in there. There is no more info in the logs.

EDIT>>> I forgot to append the controller's function associated to the HTTP call

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public Map<String, String> addIncidence(@RequestBody Incidence incidence) {
    incidenceService.addIncidence(incidence);

    Map<String, String> response = new HashMap<String, String>();

    response.put("token", incidence.getToken().toString());
    response.put("service_request_id",
            incidence.getServiceRequestIdString());
    response.put("service_notice", "some text from server");
    response.put("account_id", null);

    return response;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: PARENT_LAST is set separately for entire EAR and WAR module. Did you try both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebSphere 8.0 comes with Jackson 1.5(or 1.6) out of the box (it's repackaged and you have to explode it to check the META-INF for the version).  as such, if you want functionality introduced after 1.5(or 1.6) you'll need to reverse the classloading order.  as fnt commented above, make sure you change the order at both EAR and WAR level if you're deploying as such.